# Int value oddly resembles a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, integer

I have posted some code that I wrote here: http://ideone.com/2TrjcN included with the given output. 
Here is another copy of it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Problem2(void);

int main() 
{
    int sum2 = Problem2();
    cout << "sum2 is: " << sum2 << endl;
}

int Problem2 (void)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int isEvenPrev = 0;
    int isEvenCurr = 2;

    for (int i=3 ; i<20; i++)
    {
            // determine if i is even
            if (i%2 == 0)
            {
                    isEvenPrev = isEvenCurr;
                    isEvenCurr = i;
                    sum += (isEvenPrev + isEvenCurr);
                    cout << "isEvenPrev: " << isEvenPrev << cout << " isEvenCurr: " << isEvenCurr    << " sum: "<< sum << endl;
            }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I was fairly confident in the small algorithm, whose purpose is this: 
"Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms. "

The values of isEvenPrev is printing out to something that look like pointers, but all I am doing is setting a value thats already an int to another value thats already an int.

Can someone inform me where I might be going wrong. The Fibonacci sequence actually works, until I get to really large values. The sum becomes negative then.

Comment: the sum becomes negative because you overflow the `int`, use a `long long` instead. as for displaying the pointers, see lared's answer: you are using `cout` then send to it a `basic_ostream` object (the second `cout`), and the `void*` pointer overload of `basic_ostream<>::operator<<` kicks in.

Comment: Oh my. Thanks for the explanation too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the second `cout` from this line:

```
 cout << "isEvenPrev: " << isEvenPrev << cout << " isEvenCurr: " << isEvenCurr    << " sum: "<< sum << endl;
```